# Error in updating or upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 LTS under WSL

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Encountering error when running sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade in WSL terminal. Host machine is Windows 10 20H2 and linux distro is Ubuntu 20.04LTS. Error output is as shown below.

```
    E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 18min 1s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
    E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 17min 43s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
    E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 18min 28s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Comment: The error seems very clear the repository is not available for another 2 plus hours.

Comment: @jkariukidev - this happens when the clock gets out of sync. I'd recommend a quick and easy fix is to restart Ubuntu in WSL.

Comment: Thanks @popey I have just tried that using `wsl --terminate Ubuntu` but didnt work and also tried with `wsl --shutdown` also didnt work.

Comment: After struggling wiht the issue I realized the Windows 10 clock was not correctly set therefore set it right in syncrony with correct time and then restarted WSL and it now works fine. Thanks guys for the suggestions.